# Ajax success data called twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't understand why my data is called two times. I tried to replace append, but it doesn't work. I think it's because of my controller.

[image: Problem here]]

This is my Ajax call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#referenceProduit').change(function(){
    // On recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
    var req=$('#referenceProduit').val();
    // Requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "index.php?uc=gererReclamation&action=saisirReclamation",
        data: "referenceProduit="+req,
        dataType : "html",
        //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
        },
        // Function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
        success:function(data){
            //On affiche la réponse du serveur
            $('.result').empty();
            $('.result').prepend(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="referenceProduit" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Reference</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="referenceProduit" id="referenceProduit">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choisir</option>
            <?php foreach($lesProduits as $unProduit){?>
            <option name="<?php echo $unProduit['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $unProduit['id'];?>"><?php echo $unProduit['reference']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    switch($action){
        case 'accueil':{
            include("vue/v_accueil.php");
            break;
        }
        case 'saisirReclamation':{
            $lesSites = $pdo->getLesSites();
            $lesProduits = $pdo->getLesProduits();
            $lesClients = $pdo->getLesClients();
            $lesNatures = $pdo-> getLesNatures();
            $lesActivites = $pdo->getLesActivites();
            if(isset($_REQUEST['referenceProduit'])){
                $leProduit = $pdo->getLeProduit();
                foreach ($leProduit as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
                }
            }
            include_once("vue/v_saisirReclamation.php");
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: check. May be you have referenceProduit id multiple times in your html

Comment: there is only one referenceProduit in my view

Comment: Did you try with a different browser>

Comment: change this line $('.result').empty();  to $('.result').html(' ');

Comment: still not working .. :(

Comment: From what I think maybe you are doing something with your reference product id? Like for example redeclaring your select change functions. Is your reference product id from a previous ajax call? Like get ajax, generate your select then define your change function, thus redeclaring, iterating the defined calls. Also please check if you have another call that manually calls $('#refrenceProduit').change(). Another way which may be noted is to try to bound the element with on. Find a parent element which will not change or $(document) then call .on('change','#refrenceProduit',function(data){...})

Comment: One thing to note in firefox developer edition(aurora) with the default inspector you can view what events are bound to one element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$('.result').empty();
```

to

```
$('.result').html(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data){
    // On affiche la réponse du serveur
    $('.result').empty();
    $('.result').prepend(data);
}
```

Instead of above code, use this below code

```
success:function(data){
    // On affiche la réponse du serveur
    $('.result').html(data);
}
```

Comment: change the variable data to response in success:function(data)

Comment: change result class to result1

Comment: same again ..:(

Comment: comment this line $('.result').html(data);

Comment: Ok.So your result is giving that html twice.Check the result html you are getting.That is the problem

Comment: i think it's because of my switch from my controller, look my edit

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a look at your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#referenceProduit').change(function(){
    //on recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
    var req=$('#referenceProduit').val();
    //requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "index.php?uc=gererReclamation&action=saisirReclamation",
        data: "referenceProduit="+req,
        dataType : "html",
        //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
        },
        //function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
        success:function(data){
            //On affiche la réponse du serveur
            $('.result').empty();
            $('.result').prepend(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Your content triggers the `change` event. You need to make sure that your response does not trigger `change`. This is a simple solution using a flag:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var shouldChange = true;
$('#referenceProduit').change(function(){
    if (!shouldChange) {
        return;
    }
    //on recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
    var req=$('#referenceProduit').val();
    //requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "index.php?uc=gererReclamation&action=saisirReclamation",
        data: "referenceProduit="+req,
        dataType : "html",
        //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
        },
        //function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
        success:function(data){
            //On affiche la réponse du serveur
            shouldChange = false;
            $('.result').empty();
            $('.result').prepend(data);
            shouldChange = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: and then what i have to do ?

Comment: @LucasFrugier, have you tested this?

Comment: console.log($shouldChange) ?

Comment: @LucasFrugier, have you tried to replace your code example with the code I gave and see whether this runs twice or not?

Comment: it runs twice again yes

Comment: If you enter console.log(shouldChange) before if (!shouldChange) what is it logging to your console?

Comment: it send me true

Comment: ..only one time

Comment: can i send you my app ? maybe you will the issue .. ?

Comment: @LucasFrugier, you should create a JSFiddle with a minimal copy of your code where the problem can be reproduced. If you do that, then I am sure that either me or someone else will solve it for you. Just make sure that when you have created the JSFiddle, you let me know about it so I can help.

Comment: i can't beacause i have a database

Comment: i think it's because of my switch from my controller, look my edit